# GLFW3 glfwCreateWindow Throws Write Access Violation

Tags: c++, exception, glfw

I am trying to set up a window using GLFW3 however when I call glfwCreateWindow the program enter break mode due to a write access violation.

glfwInit have been successfully called prior to this.

The error callback receives error 65544 *"WGL: Failed to make context current"*

I am building as a 64-bit application and I am using the pre-compiled binaries provided at glfw.org

My create window function:

```
myWindow = glfwCreateWindow(800, 800, "", NULL, NULL);

if (myWindow == nullptr)
{
    return false;
}

glfwMakeContextCurrent(myWindow);

return true;
```

The error visual studio provides reads:

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FF67A835406 in Launcher_Debug.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000000001F4.

Comment: Does it work if your entire project and libraries are 32 bit?

Comment: Also, are you linking with glfw dynamically or statically?

Comment: Here's an interesting link: http://discourse.glfw.org/t/lib-glfw3-dll-crashing-on-windows-7/944/5

Comment: Another interesting link: https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/182431-Access-Violation-GLEW-GLFW3

Comment: @IvanRubinson I have tried linking both dynamically and statically but the results are very similar. When linking dynamically the error message says that the violation occurs in the dll but when linking statically it obviously just states that it occurs in my application. Thanks for the two links, I'll make sure to read through them. Finally I will try a 32 bit build and see if that works

Comment: Can you paste a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that I can run and try to reproduce your issue? It might be an initialization issue, and your question doesn't have that code in it.